# SAGA not working within sextante when QGIS processing installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga, sextante, qgis-processing

Recently i decided to start working in Ubuntu (version 14.04). My first step was to add the ubuntugis-unestable repository, and then proceed to install SAGA, GRASS, OTB, QGIS and the bindings between them (grass plugin, python-otb, python-saga, etc.). Everything but SAGA is working fine, and when i try to run any algoritm from saga i get an error message saying that SAGA is correctly installed and configured, but can't produce an output. The log for the reclassify grid values algorithm is the following:

Algorithm Reclassify grid values starting...

```
grid_tools "Reclassify Grid Values" -INPUT "/tmp/processing/653d3cd20b3d482db2dee2a8c79519bb/clipped.sgrd" -METHOD 1 -OLD 0 -NEW 1 -SOPERATOR 0 -MIN 0 -MAX 99999 -RNEW 0 -ROPERATOR 1 -RETAB "/tmp/processing/1420653021.926.txt" -TOPERATOR 0 -NODATA 0 -OTHERS 0 -RESULT "/home/ignacio/Escritorio/r_cropped_reclass.tif.sgrd"
io_gdal 1 -GRIDS "/home/ignacio/Escritorio/r_cropped_reclass.tif.sgrd" -FORMAT 1 -TYPE 0 -FILE "/home/ignacio/Escritorio/r_cropped_reclass.tif"
Error: Grid file could not be opened.
Error: input file [/tmp/processing/653d3cd20b3d482db2dee2a8c79519bb/clipped.sgrd]
Error: Grid
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.1.4

____________________________
library path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/
library name: libgrid_tools
library : Tools
tool : Reclassify Grid Values
author : Copyrights (c) 2005 by Volker Wichmann
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________

Load table: /tmp/processing/1420653021.926.txt...



Load grid: /tmp/processing/653d3cd20b3d482db2dee2a8c79519bb/clipped.sgrd...
failed

Usage: saga_cmd grid_tools 15 -INPUT [-RESULT ] [-METHOD ] [-OLD ] [-NEW ] [-SOPERATOR ] [-MIN ] [-MAX ] [-RNEW ] [-ROPERATOR ] [-RETAB ] [-TOPERATOR ] [-RETAB_2 ] [-F_MIN ] [-F_MAX ] [-F_CODE ] [-NODATAOPT ] [-NODATA ] [-OTHEROPT ] [-OTHERS ] [-RESULT_NODATA_CHOICE ] [-RESULT_NODATA_VALUE ]
-INPUT: Grid
Grid (input)
-RESULT: Reclassified Grid
Grid (output)
-METHOD: Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] single
[1] range
[2] simple table
[3] user supplied table
Default: 0
-OLD: old value
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-NEW: new value
Floating point
Default: 1.000000
-SOPERATOR: operator
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] =
[1] 
[2] 
[3] >=
[4] >
Default: 0
-MIN: minimum value
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-MAX: maximum value
Floating point
Default: 10.000000
-RNEW: new value
Floating point
Default: 5.000000
-ROPERATOR: operator
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] 
[1] 
Default: 0
-RETAB: Lookup Table
Static table
3 Fields:
- 1. [8 byte floating point number] minimum
- 2. [8 byte floating point number] maximum
- 3. [8 byte floating point number] new

-TOPERATOR: operator
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] min 
[1] min 
[2] min 
[3] min 
Default: 0
-RETAB_2: Lookup Table
Table (optional input)
-F_MIN: minimum value
Table field
-F_MAX: maximum value
Table field
-F_CODE: new value
Table field
-NODATAOPT: no data values
Boolean
Default: 0
-NODATA: new value
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-OTHEROPT: other values
Boolean
Default: 0
-OTHERS: new value
Floating point
Default: 0.000000
-RESULT_NODATA_CHOICE: Assign ...
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] NoData value of input grid
[1] user defined NoData value
Default: 0
-RESULT_NODATA_VALUE: NoData Value
Floating point
Default: -99999.000000
Error: Grid file could not be opened.
Error: executing tool [GDAL: Export Raster]
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.1.4

____________________________
library path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/
library name: libio_gdal
library : GDAL/OGR
tool : GDAL: Export Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________

Load grid: /home/ignacio/Escritorio/r_cropped_reclass.tif.sgrd...
failed
GDAL: Export Raster: could not initialize data objects
Convirtiendo salidas
Cargando las capas resultantes
Algorithm Reclassify grid values finished
```

I don't know why it doesnt work, and i am getting started with Ubuntu...could somebody help me?

Comment: I have the same issue, but SAGA algos with vectors only (no rasters involved) seem work. But I have no clue either and hope someone else has.

Comment: Days later after asking the question i discovered a possible reason: the API of SAGA have been changed but QGIS 2.6 is only prepared to support the versions 2.0.8 and 2.1.2. And thus, SAGA does not work within sextante. Here is where i found out: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11601

Comment: Ok, I see. But why the hell is ubuntu-unstable now delivering 2.1.4 and 2.1.0 ?? Thats pretty much in beetween what is supported by QGIS. But there must be some way out of this, cause I wonder why there is so few feedback on this. Actually all ppl using ubuntu-unstable with a Linux box should suffer from this, no?